# Intellij IDEA launching another icon at start

Tags: .desktop, intellij

It's hard to explain this without a picture, so I'll add one. Basically, I installed IntelliJ IDEA using [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mmk2410/+archive/ubuntu/intellij-idea-community) on 16.04. After installting, I found that typing "idea" in the standard program seach was turning up nothing, though the command `intellij-idea-community` was launching the program correctly.

So I created a `.desktop` file at `/usr/share/applications/intellij_idea.desktop` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=IntelliJ IDEA
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/intellij-idea-community/bin/idea.sh
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/intellij-idea-community/bin/idea.png
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE;
Name[en]=IntelliJ IDEA
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

And now, IDEA start showing up in search. So far so good.

I have an annoyance, though. Once IDEA starts up, the icon gets replaced by the ugly default question-mark thing (see the last icon in Unity):

[image]

Everything works fine. It's just that this icon is an eyesore. Also, if I lock this icon to launcher and then close IDEA and click on the icon to start the IDE, it doesn't. Instead, I just see a "busy" animation of this icon. To launch, I again have to type "idea" in the search and click on the png icon.

Any explanations for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What happened

`intellij-idea-community` installs a perfectly working `.desktop` file: `/usr/share/applications/intellij-idea-community.desktop`. Sometimes however, a freshly installed application needs a log out/in to show up in Dash.

This is apparently the case in your situation. I tried installing it with the same result. Simply log out/in did the job:

[image]

Your home-made launcher *does* start up the application, but does not connect to the window, so a generic icon shows up to represent the window.

#### How to fix

Remove your own made launcher from `/usr/share/applications/intellij_idea.desktop`, log out and back in.

#### important note

In any way, since you tried lock the (incorrect?) icon to the launcher, make sure to remove any Intellij IDEA - related `.desktop` file from `~/.local/share/applications`, since possibly remaining `.desktop` files will overrule the global one.

Comment: Yup! Worked fine right out of the box! :-)

Comment: @dotslash Great :)

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps:

1. get rid of the `.desktop` file you created earlier
2. start `intellij idea`
3. go to tools and select `Create desktop Entry..`
4. say yes to override whatever was there before and select the `option` `create for all users` in the dialogue box

And you should see an icon in `dash`. It appears you didn't do this after installing the app.

Comment: 1. This will not fix the issue whatsoever. 2. intellij-idea-community installs a perfectly working .desktop file in `/usr/share/applications` already. Creating *another one* locally, what you propose, will increase the mess. Remeber he installed it from ppa.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm, It does not create another one it simply overrides whatever one is there already... This is what is done when `updating` to a newer version, I do this all the time. I agree with the log out advice it does that at times.

Comment: Please read the question, he installed it ***from ppa*** with a globally installed `.desktop file`. Your proposal will create one locally. His own file (differently named) will still exist, is not overwritten (created globally), causing issues since it is named differently, calling the same application.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm, I see what your saying. Sorry didn't put my head into the question. Yes you answer should do the trick.

Comment: No problem, glad I could convince you :)

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm, selecting the `create for all users` option might also override the previously created one, right?

Comment: In principle, but his own file is differently named. The issue is that file, which is corresponding to the same application, but differently named. That one will still exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49469/discussion-between-george-and-jacob-vlijm).