# Own made .desktop doesn't show at sidebar Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Unity

Tags: unity, unity-dash, .desktop, intellij

I created my own `.desktop` file because I've moved the folders where IntelliJ IDEA was installed.

```
[Desktop entry]
Name=Intellij_IDEA
Exec=/home/jorch/Documents/1.IDEsAndPrograms/idea-IU/bin/idea.sh
Icon=/home/jorch/Documents/1.IDEsAndPrograms/idea-IU/bin/idea.png
Type=Application
Comment=Integrated Development Environment
NoDisplay=false
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;Development
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.22
```

Here is what's inside my `intellij.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications`.

I have even checked if there were some "old files" as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856061/intellij-idea-launching-another-icon-at-start).

I also tried, login out or running <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> and then `unity` to restart unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `[Desktop Entry]` rather than `[Desktop entry]`. Also make sure the path is correct.

Comment: I've changed it as you suggested, thanks! I executed `ctrl` + `f2` and then `unity` 
to reload but didn't work :( So I  copied the `.desktop` file to `~/.local/share/applications`, and so it works now!